# Linux: Define DTS Entry Without Pins on Modern Kernels (5.10+)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

In short: **How can I define a DTS entry which represents hardware without any `pinctrl` entries on Linux 5.10+?**

**Backstory**

Recently I migrated one of our embedded Linux kernels from 5.4.69 to 5.10.109.  In doing so, it appears that numerous DTS entries are broken in a similar fashion.  Consider the following sample DTS node for an internal Thermal Management Unit (tmu):

```
tmu: tmu@40008000 {
    compatible = "vendor,tmu";
    reg = <0x0 0x40008000 0x0 0x1000>;
    status = "okay";
};
```

Given that this is a fully internal device, there there are no `pinctrl-n` entries, nor should there be.  Unfortunately, this now causes driver binding to fail with:

```
vendor-tmu 40008000.tmu: no pinctrl handle (-19)
```

This error is repeated for many different internal peripherals.  Now, I can trace this error to [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.109/source/drivers/pinctrl/core.c#L1047) call returning `-ENODEV` which ultimately causes [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.109/source/drivers/base/dd.c#L537) check to jump to the `pinctrl_bind_failed` label and tear the driver down.

So, as stated above, what is the modern method to create a DTS entry without pins?

Comment: Looking at [pinctrl-bindings.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/pinctrl-bindings.txt), it looks like you're allowed to have a `pinctrl-0` entry with an empty state if you don't actually have a pin controller or relevant pins.

Comment: I saw that but I am uncertain as to how this is supposed to work.  AFAIK, `pinctrl-0 = ;` is a violation of the DTS grammar (fails to build on my setup) and `pinctrl-0 = <>;` compiles but still fails in the same manner as the question.  Is there another syntax to represent this?

Comment: Also, I just saw the `an-empty-property;` syntax (E.g. `pinctrl-0;`).  This fails identically to `pinctrl-0 = <>;` and the question.  Also, I thought this form was only for boolean properties, but I could be mistaken here.

Answer (score 1):

My particular problem was caused by some leftovers from the earlier porting effort.  How embarrassing.

To answer the specific question, DTS entries without need for pins can follow one of several approaches:

1. Just omit the `pinctrl-0` entry entirely.  There is something of a reg herring in [pinctrl-bindings.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/pinctrl-bindings.txt), in that `pinctrl-0` is listed as a required property.  Not sure why the verbiage is this way but omitting all `pinctrl-*` entries now works for me.
2. Explicitly state that the given entry has no pins via either `pinctrl-0;` or `pinctrl-0 = <>;`.  I personally like the latter as it avoids ambiguity with boolean properties.  In my testing, both worked equivalently.